# Cakephp3: How to output checkboxes into 2 colums?

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this call to output a set of checkboxes within my view:

```
<?=$this->Form->input('roles._ids', [
     'options' => $roles,
     'label' => false,
     'multiple' => 'checkbox',
     'templates' => [
           'checkboxWrapper' => '<label class="mt-checkbox">{{label}}<span></span></label>',
           'nestingLabel' => '{{input}}{{text}}',
           'inputContainer' => '<div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top: 10px;"><div class="mt-checkbox-list" data-error-container="#form_2_services_error">{{content}}</div></div>'
                                            ]]);
                            ?>
```

Does anyone know a solution - how to break the output into 2 divs?
I wanted to have half the checkboxes in a single

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="padding-top: 10px;">
```

(see line "inputContainer") div container. Is that anyhow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to separate checkbox in two columns you can do like this

```
    <?php
    $this->Form->templates([
        'checkboxWrapper' => '<div class="col-md-6">{{label}}</div>'
    ]);
    ?>
    <?=$this->Form->input('roles._ids', [
        'options' => ['asdasd','asdasd','asdasd'],
        'label' => false,
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        ]);
    ?>
```

OR you can just change the style of default template of cakehphp by adding this css

```
.checkbox {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this will help